# How do I define a \DefineSeries command similar to \DefineJournal when using AMSRefs?

Tags: bibliographies, acronyms, amsrefs

In Section 8.4 *Abbreviations:* `\DefineName`*,* `\DefineJournal`*, and* `\DefinePublisher` of the AMSRefs [package documentation](https://ctan.asis.ai/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf), the following is mentioned:

> After writing
>
> ```
> \DefineName{dmj}{Jones, David M.}
>
> \DefinePublisher{ams}{AMS}{American Mathematical Society}{Providence}
>
> \DefineJournal{jams}{0894-0347}
>   {J. Amer. Math. Soc.}
>   {Journal of the American Mathematical Society}
> ```
>
> you can use these abbrevations as follows:
>
> ```
> author={dmj} (or editor={dmj} or translator={dmj})
>
> journal={jams}
>
> publisher={ams}
> ```
>
> The second argument of `\DefinePublisher` is the abbreviated form of the publisher’s name, the third argument is the full name, and the fourth will be used as the address. If the `short-publishers` option is requested, then the abbreviation will be used; otherwise the full name will be used.
>
> Similarly, the third argument of `\DefineJournal` will be used if the `short-journals` option is requested; otherwise the fourth argument will be used. (The second argument is the ISSN of the journal, which is not currently used, but is included for future use.)

I find these to be quite handy, and would like to add another option called `\DefineSeries` to keep track of series like the [London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series](https://www.cambridge.org/core/series/london-mathematical-society-lecture-note-series/2F5027CF7EAF1D93BA12E984C5E32EE1). For instance, here is a book entry that uses the `series` entry:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsrefs}

\DefineName{wal-k}{Walker, Keith}

\DefinePublisher{cup-c}{Cambridge Univ. Press}{Cambridge University Press}{Cambridge}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\raggedright

\bib{Wal93}{book}{
      editor={wal-k},
       title={Surveys in combinatorics, 1993},
      series={London Math Soc. Lecture Note Ser.},
        ISSN={0076-0552, 2634-3681/e},
   publisher={cup-c},
        date={1993},
      volume={187},
        ISBN={978-0-511-66208-9/e},
         doi={10.1017/CBO9780511662089},
}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

Looking at the [documented source](https://ctan.asis.ai/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrefs.pdf) for how `\DefineJournal` is defined, I tried inserting the following into my preamble:

```
\newcommand{\DefineSeries}[4]{%
    \bib*{#1}{periodical}{
        issn={#2},
        series={#4}
    }%
}

\DefineSeries{lmslns}{0076-0552, 2634-3681/e}
    {London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser.}
    {London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series}
```

and then I replaced the `series` entry in the `\bib` item with `{lmslns}`. However, this does not work: I get "lmslns" as the series. What do I need to do here?

Comment: why do you use amsrefs instead of biblatex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm willing to drop `amsrefs` and shift to `biblatex` if it's recommended! So far, I've been sticking to `amsrefs` because (1) I like the `amsrefs` style; (2) it seemed to be more flexible than using plain BibTeX, which was what I was using earlier; (3) I *heard* (not sure) that journals/arXiv.org still don't accept submissions that use `biblatex`, and I'm not sure how easy it is to make the necessary adjustments in my final manuscript before shipping it off to such journals.

Comment: I think I figured out what I need to do: adding `\xref@check@b\bib'series` to the list of other cross-references that have to be resolved, inside `\def\bib@resolve@xrefs{...}` (these are lines 829–836 in the Subsubsection 6.12.3 *Resolving cross-references* of the [documented source](https://ctan.asis.ai/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrefs.pdf)), produces the `series` entry as I require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603580/how-do-i-define-a-defineseries-command-similar-to-definejournal-when-using-ams#comment1513918_603580) into an answer to remove this from the unanswered list.*

---

One needs to add the field `series` to the list of fields whose cross-references are to be resolved, so the following goes in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\catcode`\'=11
\def\bib@resolve@xrefs{%
    \xref@check@c\bib'xref
    \xref@check@a\bib'author
    \xref@check@a\bib'editor
    \xref@check@a\bib'translator
    \xref@check@b\bib'journal
    \xref@check@b\bib'publisher
    \xref@check@b\bib'series        % <--- added this line
}
\catcode`\'=12

\newcommand{\DefineSeries}[4]{%
    \bib*{#1}{periodical}{
        issn={#2},
        series={#4}
    }%
}
    
\@ifpackagewith{amsrefs}{short-journals}{%
    \renewcommand{\DefineSeries}[4]{%
        \bib*{#1}{periodical}{
            issn={#2},
            series={#3},
        }%
    }
}{}
\makeatother
```

Then, I am able to use the `\DefineSeries` command as mentioned in the OP. This will also use the short version of the series when the `short-journals` option or `abbrev` option is passed to the `amsrefs` package.